# Cordova InAppBrowser Closing Instantly iOS 13

Tags: ios, cordova, inappbrowser

I am currently facing an issue with iOS 13 and Cordova where I open an InAppBrowser screen it will come up and then instantly close/hide. There are no errors in the logs of XCode. I noticed that it was saying there was already a browser open when I try to click a different tile but there’s no animation of it trying to open after the first time.

If I build for iOS 12 in XCode 10.3 it works fine.

Thanks in advance for any possible solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same issue.

Cordova 9.0.0 
Cordova-ios 5.0.1 
InAppBrowser 3.0.0 
built with XCode 11.1 
iOS 13 has the issue 
but iOS 12 is OK

I fixed the issue by manually change the source code of InAppBrowser following the pull request below. 
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/pull/534/files

Comment: @RatanUdayKumar Actually, the link is to the relevant pull request's source codes. This answer is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Just upgraded my InAppBrowser to latest (v 4.0.0) and it has been fixed.